# Unity ios build folder is empty

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, build

I want to build my project for IOS. I choose folder and build my project. at the end of the build, my folder is empty. Why? Can you help me?

There is an error on console:

Failed running /Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/Tools/UnusedByteCodeStripper2/UnusedBytecodeStripper2.exe --api NET_2_0_Subset -out "/Users/arifsanat/Desktop/CityCars/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/tempStrip" -l none -c link -b False -x "/Applications/Unity/PlaybackEngines/iOSSupport/Whitelists/Core.xml" -f "/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/il2cpp/LinkerDescriptors" -x "/Users/arifsanat/Desktop/CityCars/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/../platform_native_link.xml" -x "/Users/arifsanat/Desktop/CityCars/Temp/StagingArea/Data/methods_pointedto_by_uievents.xml" -x "/Users/arifsanat/Desktop/CityCars/Temp/StagingArea/Data/preserved_derived_types.xml" -x "/Users/arifsanat/Desktop/CityCars/Assets/link.xml" -d "/Users/arifsanat/Desktop/CityCars/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed" -a  "/Users/arifsanat/Desktop/CityCars/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/Assembly-CSharp.dll" -a  "/Users/arifsanat/Desktop/CityCars/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.UI.dll"

stdout:
SweepReport:
System.MonoType => Mono.Cecil.TypeDefinitionMono.Cecil.TypeDefinitionMono.Cecil.TypeDefinitionMono.Cecil.TypeDefinitionMono.Cecil.TypeDefinition
Mono.Cecil.MethodDefinition => System.Void .ctor()System.Void .ctor(System.String)System.String get_Comment()System.Void .ctor()System.Boolean get_CanTransformMultipleBlocks()
Mono.Cecil.FieldDefinition => System.String commentSystem.Func`3<System.Int32,System.Int32,System.Int32> <>f__am$cache0System.Func`3 <>f__am$cache1System.Func`3<System.Double,System.Double,System.Double> <>f__am$cache2System.Func`3 <>f__am$cache3
Fatal error in Mono CIL Linker
Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve UnityEngine.RenderTexture
  at UnusedBytecodeStripper2.AddUnresolvedStubsStep.Process () <0x10afdf960 + 0x002fd> in :0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.BaseStep.Process (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) <0x1096e9ed0 + 0x0006b> in :0 
  at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) <0x1096e8f90 + 0x000e6> in :0 
  at Mono.Linker.Driver.Run (IEqualityComparer`1 typeComparer, IEqualityComparer`1 methodComparer) <0x108606520 + 0x00be7> in :0 
  at Mono.Linker.Driver.RunDriverWithErrorHandling (Mono.Linker.Driver driver, IEqualityComparer`1 typeComparer, IEqualityComparer`1 methodComparer) <0x1086064d0 + 0x00026> in :0 
  at Mono.Linker.Driver.RunDriver (Mono.Linker.Driver driver, IEqualityComparer`1 typeComparer, IEqualityComparer`1 methodComparer) <0x1086063e0 + 0x0003b> in :0

Comment: Are you sure you looked into the right folder? How long does building your project take? Did you include your scenes in the build?

Comment: yes, i am sure. it takes short time

Comment: When making a build, you can select which scenes to include in the build in the build settings. Click Files->Build Settings -> Check the scenes you want

Comment: Did you make your build using Files->Build&Run ?

Comment: yes, its folder is empty too

Comment: it always gives 3 error on console. first one is in my edit. second and thirth : Exception: /Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/Tools/UnusedByteCodeStripper2/UnusedBytecodeStripper2.exe did not run properly!

Comment: Okay, don't use Build&Run, go to the build settings instead!

Comment: Aaand it looks like your IOS build module is broken somehow

Comment: Dunno, sorry-_- probably reinstall your IOS build module. I assume this is the first time you tried to build your project?

Comment: i build it on windows for android. now i try it for ios on mac ( I may not have understood the question :) )

Comment: This is a known bug in Unity 5.5. We don't have a work around or a fix for it yet, but when we do, I'll post here. In the meantime, you may want to try using Unity 5.4 instead. You can follow the status of this bug report here: https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/ios-mono-dot-cecil-dot-resolutionexception-failed-to-resolve-unityengine-dot-rendertexture-when-building-for-ios

Comment: I installed unity 5.4 but my project doesnt work on it. how can i open my project on 5.4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have tracked down the cause of this issue. It is a bug in the UnusedBytecodeStripper2, and we should have a fix in the 5.5.1p1 patch release if all goes well.

It might be possible to work around the issue though. Some assembly in the project uses the UnityEngine.RenderTexture::generateMips property, which was renamed to autoGenerateMips in Unity 5.5. The API Updater will correctly make this change to the assembly, but in the bug report, the API Updater did not run on this assembly for an unknown reason. The assembly in this case was Vuforia.UnityExtensions.dll, but any assembly could be impacted.

So, it is possible to work around this issue by ensuring that the API Updater has been run on all assemblies in the project. You can use ILSpy or ildasm to check the content of an assembly. Make sure an assembly does not reference UnityEngine.RenderTexture::generateMips after the API Updater modified it.

Answer (score 1):

Do steps below:

1. Check your [player setting](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsiOS.html).
   For me almost trouble when build iOS App with Unity occurred here.
   (If everything okay, go to 2
2. Try to build a empty (or simple) Unity Project and make sure you can build that and run on Xcode successfully.
3. If 1. 2. is okay, so problem definitely is in your code, check your iOS plugin code (if available) first then C# code.
4. If 1.2.3 is okay, try to reinstall your Unity, Xcode app.
5. If even 4 cant resolve your problem, make a [bug report](https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/articles/206336985-How-do-I-submit-a-bug-report-).

Hope this help!

Comment: 1 and 2 is ok. I couldnt understand 3. what should i check? my code works on android. should i do anything for ios?

Comment: Sorry, i 've edited post. 
If you use iOS plugin , you should check that code. That is what i mean.

Comment: I didnt use IOS plugin code. Should i add anything to my c# code for ios?

Comment: No, you did not need to add anything to build for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. I resolved it by checking the third party plugin. Mainly this error is because of link.xml.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you are building it into the Assets folder? Try saving it to a folder outside the Unity project.

Comment: Unity 5.5.1p4 solved this problem, thanks for your answer :)